# Emma runtime controller doesnt start

Tags: maven-2, code-coverage, maven-plugin, emma

My primary goal is to get code coverage using EMMA on a running web application using CTL coverage.get.
  I use emma maven plugin.

So, I deploy my web application with instrumented code.
  In tomcat log is see:

```
EMMA: collecting runtime coverage data ...
```

but there is no:

```
EMMA: runtime controller started on port [47653]
```

Which means that Im not able to use ctl as nobody is listening for it.
  What could be the reason of runtime controller not starting?

My parent pom.xml:

```
<project>
        ...
         <build>
            <plugins>
                ...
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>   
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>instrument</id>
                                <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>instrument</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>                            
                        </executions>
                </plugin>
                ...
            </plugins>
        </build>
        ... 
        <reporting>
            <plugins>        
                ...
                <plugin>      
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>      
                </plugin>
                ...
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
        ...
    </project>
```

Thanks in advance. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
         <systemPropertyVariables combine.children="append">
             <emma.rt.control>true|false</emma.rt.control>
         </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks Stewart. This helped me out. I found you can also just add `-Demma.rt.control=false` to the mvn command.  For instance `mvn emma:emma -Demma.rt.control=false`